# Open JPA with springboot data rest giving error with PUT and DELETE operation : Cannot cast org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId to java.lang.Long

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, openjpa

I am working on an an application which uses `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` with `Open JPA`. I am using spring-boot version `1.5.3.RELEASE`.

I have a requirement to do CRUD Operation on `Person` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Phone> phones;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
private String name;


// Getters and Setters
```

`PersonRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
```

`Phone` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE")
public class Phone {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = true)
public Person person;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PHONE_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "PHONE_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PHONE_SEQ_GEN")
@Column(name = "PHONE_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PHONE_BRAND_NAME")
private String name;

//  Getters and Setters
```

Issues :

1. Using data rest , when i fire a PUT request

   curl -X PUT \
      http://localhost:8080/person/1 \
      -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{
      "name":"Test Person”
           }'

   Getting below error :
   `Cannot cast org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId to java.lang.Long`

Below is my dependency Tree:

```
testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11 -> 1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.14
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.14
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.14
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.14
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.5.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.1.Final
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.8.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.10
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.10
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.5 -> 2.8.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3 -> 1.7.25
|    |    \--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.10
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.6.1
|    |    \--- io.springfox:springfox-core:2.6.1
|    |         +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.3
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.25
|    |         +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10 -> 1.7.25
|    |         \--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |              +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |              \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10 -> 1.7.25
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.6.1
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-core:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.6.1 (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:2.6.1
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.10
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.10 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.3
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.3
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.3
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.25
|    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.0.0.Final
+--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1
|    \--- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.6.1 (*)
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 (*)
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.1
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.1 -> 2.8.8
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1 -> 2.8.8 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.1 -> 2.8.8
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 (*)
|    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
|    \--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.2
|         \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.3.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all:2.4.1
+--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1
+--- project :common
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1 (*)
|    +--- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 (*)
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.1 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.6.3.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:2.6.3.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.23.0.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.7.25
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.13.3.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25
|    |         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25 (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.atteo:evo-inflector:1.2.1
|    |         |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.7 -> 2.8.0
|    |         |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25 (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.7 -> 2.8.8 (*)
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.7 -> 2.8.0
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.5.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.14
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.5.14
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2
|    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.13.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.24 -> 1.7.25 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9 -> 1.8.10
|    +--- org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all:2.4.1
|    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.8 -> 1.8.10
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5
|    \--- org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208 -> 9.4.1212.jre7
+--- junit:junit:4.11
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12 -> 4.11 (*)
|    \--- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:1.6.6
|         +--- junit:junit:4.12 -> 4.11 (*)
|         +--- org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.6
|         |    +--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.6
|         |    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.4
|         |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.21.0-GA
|         \--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.6 (*)
+--- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19
|    |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1 -> 2.4
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:1.6.6
|         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|         \--- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.6.6
|              +--- org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.6 (*)
|              \--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.6.6 (*)
\--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.6.RELEASE
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE
```